# CompletableFuture - supply a method that returns bool value to supplyAsync call

Tags: java, asynchronous, concurrency, nonblocking, completable-future

I am getting back into Java after a long long time so apologies if the question seems stupid. I am trying to use *CompletableFuture* to create a non-blocking call. I have a method that returns a boolean

```
public boolean waitOnState(final String targetState, final long waitMs) {
        long begin = System.nanoTime()/1000000;
        synchronized (stateLock) {
            long elapsedMs = 0L;
            logger.debug(this.storeName + "-" + this.getStreamState().toString());
            while (!this.getStreamState().toString().equals(targetState)) {

                if (waitMs > elapsedMs) {
                    long remainingMs = waitMs - elapsedMs;
                    try {
                        logger.debug("Waiting on stream to be in run state in "+remainingMs);
                        stateLock.wait(remainingMs);
                    } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                        // it is ok: just move on to the next iteration
                    }
                } else {
                    logger.debug("Cannot transit to target state");
                    return false;
                }
                elapsedMs = System.nanoTime()/1000000 - begin;
            }
            logger.debug("State is running - "+this.storeName);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

And i pass this function to completedFuture in this way:

```
CompletableFuture<Boolean> resultHandle = 
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this.waitOnState("RUNNING", 100000));
        resultHandle.thenAccept(result -> System.out.println(result));
```

But I get an error `The method supplyAsync(Supplier<U>) in the type *CompletableFuture* is not applicable for the arguments (boolean)`

The error persists even if I change the return type of my function to Boolean or Integer so I am sure I am invoking the *CompletableFuture* incorrectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rather give it a supplier, so don't invoke the method inline, rather make it a lambda expression:

```
CompletableFuture<Boolean> resultHandle = 
            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 
                 this.waitOnState("RUNNING", 100000));
```

`() -> this.waitOnState("RUNNING", 100000)` is a lambda expression that the compiler can make a `Supplier` from, but `this.waitOnState("RUNNING", 100000)` is a boolean expression.

Comment: Ah, that works! working on a new language is like being a child again :)